# Issue with gradle build and pom parsing

Tags: maven, gradle, compiler-errors

I have a question on Gradle builds that I'm having difficulty in resolving.

I keep getting an error saying UPDATED:

```
> Could not resolve credit/open/fabric:credit-open-fabric-api:17.4.1.RELEASE.
  > Could not parse POM http://Mywebsite/content/groups/public/openapi/17.4.1.RELEASE/open-api-17.4.1.RELEASE.pom
     > Could not resolve open:api:17.4.1.RELEASE.
        > Could not resolve open:api2:17.4.1.RELEASE.
           > Could not parse POM http://Mywebsite/content/groups/public/open/api2/17.4.1.RELEASE/api2-17.4.1.RELEASE.pom
              > Could not resolve open:open-parent:17.4.1.RELEASE.
                 > Could not resolve open:open-parent:17.4.1.RELEASE.
                    > Could not parse POM http://Mywebsite/content/groups/public/open/open-parent/17.4.1.RELEASE/open-parent-17.4.1.RELEASE.pom
                       > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'tibco:${tibrv.native}:jar'
```

and the stack trace shows there is an issue in parsing a pom that contains the dependency as follows UPDATED:

```
<dependency>
<groupID>tibco</groupID>
<artifactId>${tibrv.native}</artifactID>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupID>tibco</groupID>
<artifactId>tibask</artifactID>
</dependency>
.
. 
.
<profile>
 <id>tib-windows</id>
 <activation>
  <os>
   <family>windows</family>
  </os>
 </activation>
 <properties>
  <tibrv.native>tibask</tibrv.native>
 </properties>
</profile>
```

In my build.gradle file I have:

```
compile 'tibco:ask:8.3.1'
```

Where nativity is the artifactID within my POM.

Is there something I need to add in my build.gradle file for the pom parser within gradle to get a true value for the `${tibrv.native}` value?

Comment: Please paste the relevant section from `pom.xml` which defines the `tibrv.native` property. Hopefully its not within a <profile>

Comment: That's exactly what it is in...

Comment: See [here](https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles) for discussion about maven profile support in gradle. And [here](https://dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices) for why using profiles in dependency management is considered an anti-pattern

Comment: Will it work if I try and using system.setProperty in java to set ${tibrv.native} value...I currently don't have permission to change the pom

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles) the `<os>` profile activation is not supported

It's possible you could set the `tibrv.native` system property, I'm really not sure but it's worth a try.

A possible workaround is to store a "fixed" version of `nativity-8.3.1.pom` in another repository which is ordered before the main repository. Maven repositories can be sourced from a local folder and I think gradle is capable of sourcing a single dependency's artifacts from multiple repositories (eg pom from one repo and jar from another) but not 100% sure.

eg:

```
repositories {
    maven {
       url uri('localrepo') // gradle will look here first
    }
    maven {
       url 'http://Mywebsite/content/groups/public'
    }
}
```

You could then store a fixed version of the pom xml at

```
$projectDir/localrepo/tibco/nativity/8.3.1/nativity-8.3.1.pom
```

Comment: Is there a way for gradle to look into the repository location and ignore the pom file located here and only use the jar within this locaiton?

Comment: I think so, see my other answer

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (not sure it'll work) is to use a configuration with `transitive = false`. Hopefully in this case gradle doesn't attempt to resolve the transitive dependencies. Obviously you'll need to add the transitive dependencies manually yourself. Also, by doing this the group/artifact/version meta-data is lost so this dependency woun't be able to participate in dependency resolution if a consumer references your project.

Eg

```
configurations {
    hack { transitive = false} 
} 
dependencies {
    hack 'tibco:nativity:8.3.1'
    compile configurations.hack.singleFile
    compile 'foo:bar:1.0'
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing is the pom file is being read and gradle is not finding the jar tibco:$tibrv.native}:jar within the repo location (it shouldn't because it doesn't exist).. Basically Gradle is not parsing the pom correctly

Comment: I was hoping that `transitive=false` meant that the dependencies in the pom were ignored. Guess I was wrong :(